# Typo 3 brings error after upgrading ubuntu

Tags: php, typo3, simplexml

I have an old Typo3 installation 7.6.31 and I did upgrade ubuntu firmware. Now I have PHP7 instead of PHP5 and it looks like Typo3 doesnt work any more. Not sure what the exact reason is, but it drops an error like this:

Oops, an error occurred!
Call to undefined function TYPO3\CMS\Core\Imaging\IconProvider\simplexml_load_string()

or is there something Missing in PHP?

how can I get my typo3 running again. I know  it's old. It will be repaced in 2 Months, but till there I would need to have it back :(

Comment: Looks like PHP XML extension is not installed. Try "apt install php7.x-xml" (where x is replaced by the PHP minor version).

Comment: You can also check the System requirements page: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/11.5/en-us/SystemRequirements/Index.html (it shows the required PHP extension). It looks like the content was restructured and I can't find the page for 7.6, but the 11.5 page should be similar enough.